# Handling axios requests that take 10+ seconds

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, axios

I hope this question isn't too general but I've got a post request that uploads a high-res image, then on the server side, several operations take place with that image to generate thumbnails and watermarks. The server takes a good 10-20 seconds before it finally returns a response. Should I be returning some kind of interim response? Is there a best practice here?

For the sake of illustration, here's a rough outline of the client-side code:

```
axios.post('/upload', hugePhoto, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } })
.then(res => { /* takes 10-20 seconds before I get a response here */ })
.catch(err => { /* handle error */ })
```

And the server-side code, note I am creating a bunch of different size images here and uploading them to S3, which is what takes so long:

```
router.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
  sharp(req.file.path).metadata()
  .then(m => /* reading metadata */)
  .then(() => /* some db operations */)
  .then(() => /* uploading original file to S3 */)
  .then(() => /* resizing the file with sharp */)
  .then(() => /* uploading that to S3 */)
  .then(() => /* resizing the file with sharp */)
  .then(() => /* uploading that to S3 */)
  .then(() => /* resizing the file with sharp */)
  .then(() => /* uploading that to S3 */)
  .then(() => res.json({ success: true }))
  .catch(err => res.status(400).send(err.message))
})
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post your server code as well please

Comment: I can post something that gives you the general idea...standby

Comment: 1 alternative is for the server to immediately respond with an endpoint the client can then poll for the response once it's ready. Though this may not buy you anything given the details you've provided so far.

Comment: @junvar how does the client know when the endpoint is ready? I am not familiar with poll?

Comment: It's a bit complicated for the comment section, but once you fire the first request, you'd kick off a task on the server to process the image, then immediately return a "check back later" response.  Then you'd set up either a socket or `setInterval` to an endpoint that can update the client when the task is complete

Comment: Thanks @Phix I get what you're saying. Maybe that is the best way to go with these large files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect use case of using serverless event driven architecture. There is no need for client to wait till you create and upload different resolutions of the images. There are multiple ways you could reduce the time.

1. Do things in parallel instead of sequentially. something like this (no change required in your current architecture)

```
router.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
  sharp(req.file.path).metadata()
  .then(m => /* reading metadata */)
  .then(() => /* some db operations */)
  .then(() => /* uploading original file to S3 */)
  .then(() => Promise.all([funcResolution1(), funcResolution2(), funcResolution3()]))
  .then(() => res.json({ success: true }))
  .catch(err => res.status(400).send(err.message))
```

2. If you are happy to change the architecture, you could leverage serverless technologies here. something like AWS Lambda (https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/). You basically take the file from endpoint and after that raise some events for the function to do the other stuff for you. OR have a trigger on s3 to trigger the function as and when there is file. that lambda function can do the thumbnails etc for you. (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/resize-images-on-the-fly-with-amazon-s3-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/)
3. You could delegate the task to some other application which gets triggered as soon as there is a file.

Hope it gives you some idea.

Comment: Man I have been reasearching this the last couple of days and thinking like nah, building the lambda functions is overkill, but the further I get on this project, the better that option seems. Thank you!